# I wanna get matched elements in array created by JSON_ARRAYAGG

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
SELECT 
    h.id,
    h.name,
    h.address,
    JSON_OBJECT(
    "lat", h.latitude,
    "lng", h.longitude) coordinate,
    h.price,
    h.guest_max guestMax,
    h.bedrooms,
    h.beds,
    h.bathrooms,
    h.thumbnail_url thumbNailUrl,
    h.user_id,
    h.area_id,
    ha.name areaName,
    (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.name) FROM hotel_convenient hc INNER JOIN convenients c ON c.id = hc.convenient_id WHERE hc.hotel_id = h.id) convenients
  FROM hotels h
  INNER JOIN hotel_areas ha ON h.area_id = ha.id 
  INNER JOIN hotel_convenient hc ON hc.hotel_id = h.id
  INNER JOIN convenients c ON hc.convenient_id = c.id
  GROUP BY h.id
  ORDER BY h.id ASC;
```

above code is my sql statments.

I have array which name is covenients created by JSON_ARRAYAGG like below

```sql
/* this is convenients column in my sql statments got from subquery */
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

I wanna get matched elements from array above

something like that

```sql
WHERE convenients INCLUDES 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
```

I know there is no INCLUDES keywords in mysql

HOW can I implement this?

Modified : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHWoM.png)

image is my output.

conveninents is array

I want to filter elements in array

something like Array.prototype.includes() in javascript.

Comment: what do you mean by "get matched elements"?  only return rows from your whole query where convenients includes foo or bar or baz?  or only include foo or bar or baz in convenients?  or something else?

Comment: I mean include foo and bar and baz in convenients but remains whole array elements

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.  please show some sample input and expected output

Comment: @ysth I added my input in picture and
if my table rows is two array of ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['test', 'test1'] about convenients and my filtering keywords is 'foo', 'bar'
my expected output is ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] array except ['test', 'test1']